# how to convert struct.pack

Tags: python, struct, byte, pack

I'm currently converting a working project from python 2.7 to python 3.6, and the issue that i'm running into is that whenever struct.pack() is used as an increment I get the error **"must be str not bytes"**.

```
    def _cmdWCS(self, cmdBytes):
        '''Returns cmdBytes with chksum appended'''
        checksum = self._calcChkSum(cmdBytes)
        cmdBytes += struct.pack('B', checksum)
        return cmdBytes
```

```
        cmd = '\xA0'
        cmd += struct.pack('BBBBBBB', 0b01,t1,t0,p1,p0,f1,f0)
        cmd = self._cmdWCS(cmd)
```

Is there anyway to convert these into strings and then bytes again so that I can recover the data properly? I've tried str(byte_string, 'utf-8') and it says I have an improper start byte.

Answer (score 0):

`struct.pack` returns a `bytes` object, but you are trying to combine that with the `str` object `'\xA0'`. Initialize `cmd` with a `bytes` object instead.

```
cmd = b'\xA0'
cmd += struct.pack('BBBBBBB', 0b01, t1, t0, p1, p0, f1, f0)
```

(Or, just fold the first byte into the call to `stuct.pack` itself.

```
cmd = struct.pack('BBBBBBBB', 0xa0, 0b01, t1, t0, p1, p0, f1, f0)
```

)